# Syntax in enum example

Tags: java, scientific-computing

In the following simple example from the Java documentation:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);
}
```

Could someone explain why the first column of digits employs the '+' sign where the second uses a more familiar scientific notation?

Thanks,

~Caitlin

Answer (score 2):

Both are definitions of exponents.

e+23 or e23 are the same thing. From what I see, column #1 is the mass, column #2 is the radius.

Answer (score 1):

I think depends on the `DecimalFormat` used to represent it, as you know the + sign is optional